# Como capturar pid de processos que estão acessando x serviço

Tags: sistema-operacional, kernel

Gostaria de saber uma forma de monitorar todos os processos que estão utilizando um serviço/funcionalidade do sistema, mais especificamente quero **monitorar os processos** que solicitam e modificam a posição do **mouse**, procurei saber como isso funciona, mas só consigo encontrar formas de alterar/visualizar esses dados utilizando ASM ou C.

Olhei esses dois links [[A]](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/io-devices-mouse.html) [[B]](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33.html) sobre a manipulação com ASM, mas mesmo assim parece que esse recurso do sistema não tem um controle pela kernel, sei que isso não é bem assim, todos os recursos tem uma especie de controle.

Resumindo: quero saber onde posso consultar diretamente os processos que estão lendo e escrevendo nos endereços referentes ao mouse;

> A linguagem é o sistema não são importantes, qualquer resultado é bem
>   vindo isso não deixa minha pergunta ampla de mais ou fora do escopo,
>   estou questionando uma forma de acessar uma informação do sistema.

Comment: Isso vai depender *totalmente* do sistema operacional. A forma que poderia ser feito no Windows, por exemplo, é totalmente diferente da do Linux ou OS X. Os tutoriais que você viu falam de interrupções da BIOS.

Comment: sim eu imaginei a diferença entre os dois sistemas, sobre os tutoriais, imaginei que seria uma forma de acesso direto ao dispositivo ):
queria saber mesmo se, e como os sistemas controlam essas chamadas

Comment: Da para escrever bastante coisa sobre isso :). Um modo fácil para saber qual o processo está a modificar a posição do mouse é através da função `GetCursorPos` para obter as coordenadas e usar `WindowFromPoint` para obter a *handle* da janela onde foi lançado o clique, e com `GetWindowThreadProcessId` você obtêm o *id* dessa janela e com e com `OpenProcess` você recupera a *handle* do processo e finalmente, chama a função `QueryFullProcessImageName` com ela você recupera o executável que está a fazer isso. Caso interesse algo para Linux, há o [`ptrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace)

Comment: Pelo que parece o Windows usa [`Mouclass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542367(v=vs.85).aspx) para lidar com os eventos do mouse e com [`Hooking`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468841(v=vs.85).aspx) também é possível usando [essa chamada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx) de retorno, as coordenadas podem ser obtidas pela estrutura [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa [página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557557(v=vs.85).aspx) também.

Comment: @QMechanic73, estou olhando os links, infelizmente não seria possível pegar o pid pela janela corrente, pois a ideia é identificar Quem é que está manipulando o mouse, por exemplo capturar um bot que está manipulando o dispositivo.